# How can i move to particular tab view in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, tabview

I am new to ASP.NET. I am using MVC4 and MongoDB. In my Page having three tabs, i am navigate to second tab here i do some process after in that page have one back button, when i press that back button, it's default move to first tab, how can i move to my second tab.

My Screen like

[image]

[image]

Please Help Me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this jquery UI tab?

Comment: No this is normal UI tab...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your controller  and enter that code

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("View name", "controller name") + "#ui-tabs-2");
```

**Example:**

```
 return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Home", "Admin") + "#ui-tabs-2");
```

It works fine.